# mysql multiple id sum values group by id within date range

Tags: mysql

where is sql query mistake? I want to sum values for multiple id within  date ranges.

```
SELECT date,ledger_name, sum(credit),sum(debit) 
from tbl_account 
WHERE ledger_name in(19,20,25,29) 
group by ledger_name and  
WHERE date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND  '$to_date'
```

Comment: Why there are two where clause? Is it typo?.

Comment: @sam, for multiple id group by id  and date ranges

Comment: SELECT date,ledger_name, sum(credit),sum(debit) from tbl_account  WHERE date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND  '$to_date' group by ledger_name in(19,20,25,29)

Comment: The restriction applied after grouping is HAVING clause restriction, not WHERE clause. But there is no aggregate functions in your query, so the second restriction must be attached to the first pre-grouping restriction.

Comment: [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) has a very specific format that should be looked at when the error is syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` clause looks like an odd mixture of grouping and filtering:

```
GROUP BY ledger_name and  
WHERE date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
```

This is in violation of the syntax. Filtering should be done in the `WHERE` clause, which always precedes `GROUP BY`, while the `GROUP BY` clause should only contain the list of grouping columns. In this case, based on the columns you are selecting:

```
date, ledger_name, SUM(credit), SUM(debit)
```

your `GROUP BY` list should be:

```
date, ledger_name
```

This filter:

```
date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
```

should be added to the `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY`, where you are already filtering on `ledger_name`. In this case you need to use `AND` to combine the two conditions:

```
ledger_name IN (19,20,25,29)
AND date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
```

Here is the complete query after applying all the fixes:

```
SELECT
  date, ledger_name, SUM(credit), SUM(debit) 
FROM
  tbl_account 
WHERE
  ledger_name IN (19,20,25,29)
  AND date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date'
GROUP BY
  date, ledger_name;
```

You can find more information in the manual:

- [SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/select.html)